# React/axios Fetch data before rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm working on a react app and I'm trying to fetch data before the rendering. I have tried a lot of solution available on the NET but nothing seems to work.
I'm trying to fetch datas from my nodeJS server, (the files from the services folder so I can manage them, add them etc..)

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Checkbox from './Checkbox';
import axios from 'axios';

const OPTIONS = [];

console.log('dd');

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    checkboxes: OPTIONS.reduce(
      (options, option) => ({
        ...options,
        [option]: false,
      }),
      {}
    ),
    load: true,
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.callF();
    this.setState({load: false});
  }

  selectAllCheckboxes = (isSelected) => {
    Object.keys(this.state.checkboxes).forEach((checkbox) => {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        checkboxes: {
          ...prevState.checkboxes,
          [checkbox]: isSelected,
        },
      }));
    });
  };

  callF = () => {
    console.log('Yes');
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3007/service')
      .then(function (response) {
        response.data.forEach((element) => {
          if (OPTIONS.indexOf(element) === -1 && element !== 'Master.js' && element !== 'command.txt') {
            OPTIONS.push(element);
          }
        });
        console.log('----' + OPTIONS);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('{' + error + '}');
      });
  };

  selectAll = () => {
    this.selectAllCheckboxes(true);
    console.log('HEY');
  };

  deselectAll = () => this.selectAllCheckboxes(false);

  handleCheckboxChange = (changeEvent) => {
    const {name} = changeEvent.target;

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      checkboxes: {
        ...prevState.checkboxes,
        [name]: !prevState.checkboxes[name],
      },
    }));
  };

  handleFormSubmit = (formSubmitEvent) => {
    formSubmitEvent.preventDefault();

    Object.keys(this.state.checkboxes)
      .filter((checkbox) => this.state.checkboxes[checkbox])
      .forEach((checkbox) => {
        console.log(checkbox, 'is selected.');
      });
  };

  createCheckbox = (option) => (
    <Checkbox
      label={option}
      isSelected={this.state.checkboxes[option]}
      onCheckboxChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
      key={option}
    />
  );

  createCheckboxes = () => {
    console.log('|||' + OPTIONS);
    OPTIONS.map(this.createCheckbox);
  };

  render() {
    const {load} = this.state;
    if (!load) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row mt-5">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
              {this.createCheckboxes()}
              <ul>{OPTIONS}</ul>
              <div className="form-group mt-2">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2" onClick={this.selectAll}>
                  Select All
                </button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2" onClick={this.deselectAll}>
                  Deselect All
                </button>
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.forceUpdate();
                  }}>
                  reload
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I tried calling props, using `componentWillMount` and `ComponentDidMount` but well I'm not good at this I guess.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question ? what exactly you are expecting?

Comment: i'd like to display a list of file with a checkbox at the right of each element, so i need to fetch data from my server, but the rendering is done before the fetching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that you need to fetch data BEFORE rendering, I'm guessing that you are getting the data, but after rendering.
In this cases please consider conditional rendering.
For example, add a new state which will keep loading status. Set it to true initially. When you fetched something - set the loading to false.
And based on the loading status (when it's false) you can render everything you need.

EDIT:
You are not updating your loading status when fetched - please remove quotes:
You have - `this.setState({'load': false});`
Try `this.setState({load: false});`

Comment: I already tried this, like this :  ```const {load} = this.state;
    if (!load)
    {
      return null;
    }```

Comment: well, it seems that you are not changing the loading state when fetched.

Comment: You have -   this.setState({'load': false});  Try   this.setState({load: false});